# What is the difference between "career" and "job" and "profession"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the difference between *career*, *job* and *profession*?

I do not understand the differences. Can you explain them?

Comment: Dictionary look-up questions are off-topic here. In your question could you add the definitions you found, and what part(s) are unclear?

Comment: I do not know when we can use one of them.

Comment: For example:I am a writer - that is my profession/job/career.

Comment: Can we use them instead of each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'job' means something you do to get money, but isn't necessarily your profession.

'Career' is a job you do based on your profession, so for example, if your career was a computer software developer, your profession might be a computer scientist.

'Profession' is something that you are good at or something that you studied, so you have extra knoledge in that field.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but your example is not correct.  A computer scientist writes operating systems,  kernels, algorithms, and does much more interesting things that just fixing computers; that would be a computer technician.

Comment: Fixed it. Changed it to 'software dev'